# Lua: How to reference a lua method inside a lua class from C for later use?

Tags: lua

I get a reference to a lua method which is inside a class with the funcion luaL_ref. When I want to call that method I use the function lua_rawgeti to push the function into the stack and then I use lua_pcall to actually call the method.Everithing works fine except that I cannot acces other class members from the method because self is nil.

Does anyone know how can I fix this ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Lua "methods" are actually functions. They have no notion of `self` like in other languages. Like gwell says, the `obj:method(...)` is actually syntactic sugar for `obj.method(obj, ...)`.

If you need to work with objects, don't save references to object functions - save the reference to object itself. You can use the following code to call a method using Lua C API:

```
/* get the object, idx is the identifier returned by luaL_ref */
lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, idx);
lua_getfield(L, -1, "method");
/* push parameters - the object first, then the rest, then call the function */
lua_pushvalue(L, -2);
...
lua_call(L, nParams + 1, 1);
```

Comment: However when defining a function as `function obj:foo() print(self.property) end` the self parameter _is_ implied.

Comment: Well, yes, if you define your function as `function Class:method(a,b)`, then it actually has three parameters - `self`, `a`, `b`. You can name the first parameter any name you want by using `function Class.method(this, a, b)` syntax. But this this does not change anything about the solution - ref-ing the object instead of the method (but you need to know the method name). The call protocol is then to pass the object as the first parameter to the method, followed by the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The Lua colon operator uses syntactic sugar to place the table being referenced as the first parameter (a.k.a. `self`) in a function call. You should be able to put the table (object) as the first parameter to the function call and it should fix your problem.